# "Any thoughts" in Latin

Tags: idiom, word-choice, interrogative, conversational

How would one translate "any thoughts?" into Latin?
It is an ellipse for "does anyone have any thoughts?"

I would think "ullas cogitationes?" for "Aliquis ullas cogitationes habet?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a noun for this purpose, I suggest *sententia*.
It means things like thought, judgement, opinion, decision, and wish.
You could just ask "sententiae?" or maybe add a verb and go "habe(ti)sne sententias?" to stay close to the English original.
Whether you should use the nominative *sententiae* or the accusative *sententias* in the standalone option depends on the implied verb.
"[Are there] any thoughts?" would take the nominative, "[Do you have] any thoughts?" the accusative.

I think a more idiomatic choice would be to use *quid* with a verb, similarly to "what do you think?".
My first instinct is to go with *censere*, but *putare* or others can work too.
A decent choice in a situation like that would be "quid cense(ti)s?".

This looks like a case where you could well use *numquid* instead of *quid*.
This makes the question more "do you have any thoughts" than "what do you think", and this is the desired direction here.
This feels like the most idiomatic choice to me.
My best suggestion is:

> *Numquid censetis?* (when addressing several people)
>   *Numquid censes?* (when addressing one person)

Comment: I agree. _Numquid censetis?_ sounds quite idiomatic and appropriate. By the way, as for the less idiomatic alternative you mention above ("You could just ask 'sententiae?'"), I think it would be better to put it in accusative.

Comment: @Mitomino I like *numquid censetis* quite a lot too for this purpose. I added the accusative option to the standalone version. I could see the implicit part being *habetisne* or *suntne*, and they take different cases. But that is secondary, as a more natural phrasing takes a different approach.